# Javascript textarea line break into database for result as JSON String

Tags: javascript, html, json, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save the textarea line breaks to the database (Mongoose - MongoDB latest). For frontend I'm working with iQuery or simple Javascript.

I'm getting currently the following error message from json parse

> VM533:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
> in JSON at position 207
> at JSON.parse ()
> at profil:390

Json line which created this error

```
"My name is example

 My name is example"}
```

In my Database is no \n or other html codes saved.

[image]

I need to save the textarea line breaks into the database for the result json string with json parse, has anyone a workaround?

**UPDATE1**
The JSON Result is only a snipped. Here is the full json result it's works perfect if the profile_description has NO line breaks

```
{"_id":"XYZ","business_id":"7XYZ","banner_url":"XYZ","__v":0,"profile_description":"My name is example

My name is example"}
```

Comment: Your “Json line which created this error” is not valid JSON to begin with. You can not have line break in normal JS text literals that are delimited with double quotes.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, that was only a snipped from my json. So if I have no line breaks in my profile_description there is no error. I have updated the full json result which works fine without line breaks.

Comment: Replace the line breaks with the characters `\n` then, before you try to parse this as JSON?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, a found a workaround but is there any possibility to get the textarea content with \n ? Because the value of textarea is always without any tags in console.log on the client side.

Comment: No idea what _“without any tags”_ is supposed to mean here. _“but is there any possibility to get the textarea content with \n ?”_ - you get it with the _actual_ line breaks, as entered by the user. If you want those to be anything else, then you have to replace them, after you read the value from the textarea.

Comment: @CBroe If there is a line break in textarea, the output from $(this).val() is in console.log is still without \n or any other tags

Comment: Of course, because the console does actually break the content into a new line at this point. Why should it _add_ something to that, that isn’t even there in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe Okay that makes sense. My workaround now is that I replace \n with <br>, I store that in the database and when reading out I then replace <br> with \n
Because I have no idea how to save the textarea content with \n. in Mongoose it seems that \n is also automatically replaced with a new line.

Comment: You need to properly differentiate between _code_, and _data_. The value you read from the textarea with `$(this).val()`, that is _data_. In there, you have an _actual_ line break, hexadecimal byte value `0A`. But JSON is _code_, that needs to get _parsed_ - so it has to follow the syntax rules of JavaScript, and those say, you can not have an actual line break in a simple text literal - so it would need to be replaced with the _characters_ `\n`. `var test = "foo\nbar"` is the JavaScript way to write a text literal delimited by double quotes, that contains a line break.

Comment: So do `var foo = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, "\\n")`, and you get a text that actually contains the characters `\n` in the places, where before there was an actual line break. _That_ can be interpreted as _code_ now, and therefor also properly be parsed, when put inside JSON.

Comment: @CBroe That works perfect. Thank you so much that helps a lot! You can create a answer in this topic. Then I can mark as solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Json line which created this error
>
> ```
> "My name is example 
> My name is example"}
> ```

That is not valid JSON to begin with.

In JavaScript, a text literal delimited by single or double quotes, can not contain an actual line break. It would either need an `\` at the end of every line, or the line breaks would need to be replaced with the characters `\n` inside the text literal.

It is important to always properly differentiate between *data*, and *code*.

When you read the field value using `$(this).val()`, the result is *data*. In there, you have an actual line break, hexadecimal byte value `0A`.

But JSON is *code*, it needs to get *parsed*. So it has to follow the basic syntax rules for text literals, that JavaScript imposes.

So those line breaks would need to be replaced by the characters `\n`, which can be done simply by

```
someVariableContainingText = someVariableContainingText.replace(/\n/g, "\\n")
```

That would get you `"My name is example\nMy name is example"` here, and that now is a valid JS text literal. As soon as your JSON contains that, instead of an actual line break, it can be parsed properly.